# MVC4 - Passing model between views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have a model what i want fill in steps like this: 
actionresult1(model)->actionresult2(model)-actionresult3(model)

My model for exaple is Person:

```
public class Person{
  string FirstName {get;set;}
  string Lastname {get;set;}
  int Age {get;set;}
}
```

In my PersonController i have three ActionResults:

```
public ActionResult FillFirstName(Person model)//First page where i start. Model is empty
    {
            return View("~/Views/FillFirstName.cshtml", model);           
    } 
public ActionResult FillLastName(Person model)//Second page, where first name is filled
    {
            return View("~/Views/FillLastName.cshtml", model);           
    } 
public ActionResult FillAge(Person model)//When i click submit button in FillLastName.cshtml view then it submits form here and model have filled only LastName and FirstName is empty.
    {
            return View("~/Views/FillAge.cshtml", model);           
    }
```

And my three views are:

1)FillFirstName.cshtml

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("FillLastName", "Person"))
{
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)
   <input type="submit" name="Next" value="Next" />
}
```

2)FillLastName.cshtml

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("FillAge", "Person"))
{
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName)
   <input type="submit" name="Next" value="Next" />
}
```

3)FillAge.cshtml

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("NextAction", "Person"))
{
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Age)
   <input type="submit" name="Next" value="Next" />
}
```

Problem: When i try to pass model between views it contains olny this data what i have submited on last view.

Reason: I have form what is 2000 lines, and i want to cut it into smaller pieces.

Is there someway i can use Viewbag or ModelState or something to keep the model filled with all data what i have submitted on previous pages? Can someone give me some example please? :)

Comment: You can use Session if you wish

Answer (score 1):

HTTP is stateless - the model can only be bound from what's in the current request. Therefore, to have access to everything in your last controller action, you need to make sure everything is sent in the request's form post. Use hidden fields to persist data over multiple views:

FillLastName:

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("FillAge", "Person"))
{
   @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.FirstName)
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName)
   <input type="submit" name="Next" value="Next" />
}
```

FillAge:

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("NextAction", "Person"))
{
   @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.FirstName)
   @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.LastName)
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Age)
   <input type="submit" name="Next" value="Next" />
}
```

This is a cleaner and more conventional way of persisting form data over multiple requests than using "pseudo-state" mechanics like session state.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention the reason.I edited my post: I have form what is 2000 lines, and i want to cut it into smaller pieces.
So, if i have to put all that data in hidden fields then i end up with 10 forms with 2000 lines :P

Comment: Then does it really need to be in separate actions? Why not just split it up into logically grouped editor templates or partials? It sounds like you need to post a bit more about the actual problem.

Comment: I did it with session.